# WebDriver Marionette from C#?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, firefox-marionette

Will Marionette be supported from C#(.NET, dotnet)?
If not yet, is there any plan to do so by release or soon?

I only found Python and JS clients mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette.

I also reviewed current Selenium C# API doc http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html and couldn't find mention of Marionette.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though they are integrated as of

> Selenium 2.46.1 onwards.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver for details.

#### Older answer

A couple points:

- Marionette is not Selenium. They are different products with very similar goals.
- It consists of a server and a client. The clients are implemented in JavaScript and Python, but implementing a C# client should be possible.

There is an example of [the server API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/Developer_setup):

```
66:{
  "from": "root",
  "applicationType": "gecko",
  "traits": []
}
```

One of the people who developed it at Mozilla is [Mark Côté](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/mrcote). The [A-team page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Auto-tools/The_Ateam) also lists several people to contact if you need to.